# Socket Send method... Is it OK to send large amounts of data in one method?

Tags: c#, performance, networking, data-loss

I'm just wondering if doing this will cause any problems such as data loss or slower bandwidth. I may be sending 256KB of data and I want to know if I should split it into smaller chunks and send those individually or if I can just do it all at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, at the application level, you should not worry about this. The low level software and network hardware will do a much better job than you will of splitting your data up into appropriately sized chunks based on network settings, link speeds, protocol frame/packet sizes, etc.

If anything, trying to split your data into smaller chunks, and getting it wrong, will force the network layer to generate even *more* smaller chunks and waste bandwidth with extra headers and overhead.

If your application is very, very performance sensitive there are things you can do to alleviate it but they are very much premature optimization -- deal with those problems if and when you actually have them.

Comment: What about sending, for instance, a 2GB file. Would you still not chunk the data?

Comment: @ByteBlast Unless you can hold the entire file in memory, which is pretty pointless anyway, you have to chunk it, but you should use big chunks as possible, by which I mean 64-128k.

Comment: @EJP Know of any good code samples of chunking and sending a file?

Comment: @ByteBlast any open source FTP or HTTP client will have examples of sending large files in chunks. But as EJP said, those chunks are usually big, and they are done for "higher level" reasons (restart/recovery, progress tracking, memory constraints, parallel transfers) and for network performance reasons.

Comment: If windows, you can use transmit file http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565(v=vs.85).aspx but see remarks for files over 2Gb. Removes need for self chunking.